# flutter Rewind deleted index

Tags: flutter, dart

i am creating an app which require me to rewind the previous swipe after removing from list. Base on research i found out that i can use this [plugin](https://pub.dev/packages/undo) or [this pligin](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_undo)
but the i cant use it because it does not suite what i want.

for example

```
//i have list of contact

List<contact> cont = [090,000,98,090,767,]
```

so if i remove the index 0 and 1,
so i will left with

```
List<contact> cont = [98,090,767,]
```

if i click a rewind button first time it should return the index 1 back to the list

```
List<contact> cont = [000,98,090,767,]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create a new list and each time you remove an element from the original list add that element to the new list. When you click rewind take the first item from the new list and add it as as the first elemet of the original list. Don't forget to remove the first element from new list when you rewind.

Comment: is adding it two times to the list back

Comment: Can you post the code here please?

Comment: i have figure out why is taking adding it, two times.... Thanks

Comment: Nice. Glad it worked 